# Radical of a ring of size p^7

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose $p$ is prime, $R$ is a ring of size $p^7$, and $J$ is the Jacobson Radical of $R$.

In general, $R/J$ is isomorphic to a direct product of matrix rings over fields.

Does there exist a ring of size $p^7$ such that
$$R/J \cong GF(p^3) \times GF(p^2)$$
or
$$R/J \cong GF(p^2) \times GF(p^2)?$$

Edit: the first case is possible by choosing
$$R = GF(p^3) \times GF(p^2)[x] / <x^2>$$